# Register interface only with class that directly inherits it in Scrutor

Tags: asp.net-core, inheritance, dependency-injection, interface, scrutor

I'm using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) to register all types in my assembly that implement interfaces. However, I want to exclude types that inherit non-abstract types that implement an interface.

I have a code structure similar to the following (all type members omitted for brevity):

```
interface IBar {}

interface IFoobar : IBar {}

class Bar : IBar {}

class Foobar : Bar, IFoobar {}
```

In `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Scan(s => s.FromCallingAssembly().AddClasses(false).AsImplementedInterfaces());
```

This results in two registrations for `IBar`, one with implementation type `Bar` and one with implementation type `Foobar`. What I want is one registration for `IFoobar` (resolves to `Foobar`) which I get, but just one registration for `IBar` which resolves to `Bar`.

`Foobar` derives from `Bar` because it requires functionality in `Bar` while `IFoobar` extends `IBar`.

Is there a way to ensure that an interface is only registered once with the class that inherits it directly and not via base classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out using a `RegistrationStrategy` as per [here](https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/#handling-duplicate-services-with-a-replacementstrategy) (the link wrongly calls it `ReplacementStrategy`). I simply search for and register a matching interface *after* registering all implemented interfaces first, but using a 'replace by implementation type' `RegistrationStrategy`.

```
services.Scan(s => s
    .FromCallingAssembly()
    .AddClasses(false)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Replace(ReplacementBehavior.ImplementationType))
    .AsMatchingInterface());
```

This does the job!